# Livewire 3 dispatch after validate function

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to migrate from plain blade to livewire but I am struggling to call swewtalert2 after getting error from `$this->validate();`. Could someone suggest me the best practice to do so?

I tried to use `addEventListener` to use dispatch function but since I am using `$this->validate();`, there is no way to intercept and dispatch the function.

Comment: *$this->validate()* rises an exception on failure, you can insert it in a try - catch

Answer (score -1):

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Chech validated data
        $validated = $validator->validated();
        ...->addEventListener()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you answer seem out of context/wrong.